# How to replace multiple values within a column using lapply?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lapply

I'm trying to run the following code which replaces all the values "dfb1" with 1 within a column P for mutliple values such as "dfb2" with 2 ..... until "dfb10" with 10. 
Here is the code:

```
out3 %>%
   mutate(P=replace(P, P=="dfb1", 1))
```

Here is how I tried to iterate this using lapply:

```
func2 <- function (k) {
  out3 %>%
    mutate(P=replace(P, P==paste0("dfb", 1:k), k))
  } 

k <-10
lapply(out3, func2)
```

Unfortuantely the code doesn't work. I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to replace the string `dfb` with "".

```
library(dplyr)

out3 %>% mutate(P = gsub("dfb", "", P))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you explain why paste0 doesn't work here?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps the replace function is not designed to be able to perform such vectorization task.